# React Table - selecting a single row

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I had been trying to figure out a few things. I got this code from a post here it seems to work with my table.
In the code below, I am trying to figure out how I can save the value of the first column of the selected row.

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useTable, useRowSelect } from "react-table";
import COLUMNS2 from './columns2'

const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
    ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
      const defaultRef = React.useRef();
      const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);
      
      return (
        <>
          {/*<input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />*/}
          <input type="radio" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
        </>
      );
    }
);


function TrackingTable2 ({data1}) {
    const data = useMemo(() => data1, [data1]);
    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS2, []);

 //   const [val, setVal] = useState('');

    const [selectedRowId, setSelectedRowId] = useState(null);
    const selectedRowIds = [];
    if (selectedRowId) {
        selectedRowIds.push(selectedRowId);
    }

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        footerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
        toggleAllRowsSelected,
        toggleRowSelected,
        } = useTable( {columns, data, }, 
            useRowSelect,
            hooks => {hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
                {
                    id: "selection",
                    Cell: ({ row }) => (
                        <div>
                            <IndeterminateCheckbox
                                {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()}
                                onClick={() => {
                                    toggleAllRowsSelected(false);
                                    toggleRowSelected(row.id, true);
                                  /*I want to save the value of the 
                                     first column here, pass the value 
                                     and open the record's                                  
                                     component form, save the edits on 
                                     the form, close the form then 
                                     figure out how to come 
                                     back here to the table */  
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )
                  },
                  ...columns
                ]);
            }
        );    
    
    return (
        <div>
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
                {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                            <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                                {column.render("Header")}
                            </th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row) => {
                    prepareRow(row);
                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                                    {cell.render("Cell")}
                                </td>;
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                {footerGroups.map((footerGroup) => (
                    <tr {...footerGroup.getFooterGroupProps()}>
                        {footerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                            <th {...column.getFooterProps()}>
                                {column.render("Footer")}
                            </th>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TrackingTable2
```

I want to pass the value of the first column to another Component and open the row in a record form.

I appreciate your help. Thanks.